# How to pass TForm and TPanel to a function?

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-xe7

I have these two functions

```
procedure GradiantFill(Control: TCustomControlEx; ColorTop, ColorBtm: TColor); overload;
procedure GradiantFill(Control: TForm; ColorTop, ColorBtm: TColor); overload;
```

Both function need access to the canvas so in order to get access to TPanel's canvas, I declare:

```
TYPE
  TCustomControlEx= class(TCustomControl)    { Control that exposes the Canvas property. It can be used to access TPanel's canvas property for example }
   public
      property Canvas;
   end;
```

I would like to merge the two functions into a single one so I can pass both TForm and TPanel to it. Like:

```
procedure GradiantFill(Control: TWinControl?; ColorTop, ColorBtm: TColor);
```

How do I achieve this in Delphi?
The problem is the the common ancestor for TPanel and TForm is TWinControl but it doesn't have a Canvas property.

Comment: Does the control really need to be passed into your gradient fill procedure? Maybe Bounds, Canvas and your two colors are enough? `procedure GradiantFill(const Bounds: TRect; ACanvas: TCanvas; ColorTop, ColorBtm: TColor);`

Comment: Yep - just pass the canvas directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
procedure GradiantFill(Control: TWinControl; ColorTop, ColorBtm: TColor);
var
  Canvas: TCanvas;
begin
  if Control is TCustomControl then
    Canvas:=TCustomControlEx(Control).Canvas
  else if Control is TForm then
    Canvas:=TForm(Control).Canvas
  else
    exit;

  ... 
end;
```

or pass the Canvas as argument instead of the Control

```
procedure GradiantFill(Canvas: TCanvas; ColorTop, ColorBtm: TColor);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. How wasn't it obvious to me?        -             PS: TCustomForm might be better than TForm.